# Replace function-pointer implementation with std::function for using lambdas in PlayFab SDK

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, function-pointers, std-function

I'm currently trying to include the [PlayFab C++ SDK](https://api.playfab.com/sdks/cocos2d-x) into my app. This SDK is mainly for the game engine Cocos2d-x, but can be used for any C++ app basically.

It's just plain REST, hence you send requests to their servers and wait for the response. This would be perfect for using lambdas.

They declare this callback, which is called when a request is successful:

```
template<typename ResType> using ProcessApiCallback = void(*)(const ResType& result, void* userData);
```

Unfortunately, they're not using std::function, but a function pointer. This way one can not use lambdas that capture variables.

Hence, I thought I could simply replace this function pointer callback with an std::function callback like so:

```
template<typename ResType> using ProcessApiCallback = std::function<void(const ResType& result, void* userData)>;
```

Unfortunately, things are not that simply, as they stored the function pointers using ugly reinterpret_casts, here's an example (remove unnecessary parts to keep it short):

```
void PlayFabClientAPI::LoginWithAndroidDeviceID(
    LoginWithAndroidDeviceIDRequest& request,
    ProcessApiCallback<LoginResult> callback,
    ErrorCallback errorCallback,
    void* userData
    )
{
    // here they assign the callback to the httpRequest
    httpRequest->SetResultCallback(reinterpret_cast<void*>(callback));
    httpRequest->SetErrorCallback(errorCallback);
    httpRequest->SetUserData(userData);

    PlayFabSettings::httpRequester->AddRequest(httpRequest, OnLoginWithAndroidDeviceIDResult, userData);
}
```

Later on, when the request was successful, they do this:

```
if (request->GetResultCallback() != nullptr)
{
    ProcessApiCallback<LoginResult> successCallback = reinterpret_cast<ProcessApiCallback<LoginResult>>(request->GetResultCallback());
    successCallback(outResult, request->GetUserData());
}
```

The HttpRequest class has this field:

```
void* mResultCallback;
```

The problem is that I don't know how to store arbitrary std::function pointers in the HttpRequest class and then later cast them back. I tried many things, including also really ugly reinterpret_casting, but nothing did work.

I'm open to do any changes to their SDK. I also reported this as bad design and they agreed, but they don't have the time to improve it, but they will accept pull request if a good solution can be found.

Comment: Do you have C++17 `std::any` or `boost::any`?  Those make it easy.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, I'm restricted to C++11 and no boost if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key item of information here is the `userData` pointer. It is supplied as part of the request, and it gets passed back to your callback function. This is an opaque pointer that the library pays no attention to, otherwise, except to forward it to your callback.

And this is what you will use, here.

This is a very common design pattern with generic service-oriented libraries that are written in C. Their APIs are often structured this way: they accept a request with an extra opaque pointer. They store this pointer, and they pass it back to the user-supplied callback, when the request completes.

The callback, then, uses it to associated any kind of additional metadata with the request.

This is a C++ library, but they chose to implement a C-style design pattern for library callbacks. That's unfortunate.

But, anyway, in your case you're going to dynamically allocate either your `std::function`, or some class's instance that contains your `std::function`, and any other data it needs, and pass the pointer to the dynamically-allocated structure to the request.

When your callback gets invoked, it simply needs to `reinterpret_cast` the opaque pointer to the dynamically-allocated type, copy its contents, `delete` it (in order to avoid memory leaks, of course), then proceed to use the copied contents as part of the callback action (whether it involves invoking the `std::function`, or something else, is immaterial).

Given that this is a C++ library you're using, and not a C library, it is unfortunate that they chose to implement this C-style opaque pointer pass-through design pattern. There are, of course, better ways to implement this in C++, but this is what you have to work with, so you'll have to deal with one ugly `reintepret_cast`. No way to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit on the answer by @SamVarshavchik here's a code snippet which should handle most of the process of generating a `userData` pointer and a "stateless" callback function taking the `userData` for you:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void c_callback_adaptor(Args... args, void* userData) {
    auto callable = reinterpret_cast<T*>(userData);
    (*callable)(args...);
}

template <typename Fn>
struct genCCallback_impl;
template <typename Res, typename... Args>
struct genCCallback_impl<Res(Args...)> {
    template <typename T>
    static std::pair<std::unique_ptr<std::decay_t<T>>,
                     Res (*)(Args..., void*)>
    gen(T&& callable) {
        return std::make_pair(
            std::make_unique<std::decay_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(callable)),
            c_callback_adaptor<std::decay_t<T>, Args...>);
    }
};

template <typename Fn, typename T>
auto genCCallback(T&& callable) {
    return genCCallback_impl<Fn>::gen(std::forward<T>(callable));
}
```

And a simple example of usage:

```
extern void registerCallback(void (*callbackFn)(int, int, void*), void* userData);

void test(int n) {
    auto cCallback = genCCallback<void(int, int)>(
        [n](int x, int y) {
            std::cout << n << ' ' << x << ' ' << y << '\n';
        });
    registerCallback(cCallback.second, cCallback.first.get());
    // for demo purposes make the allocated memory permanent
    (void) cCallback.first.release();
}
```

(Of course, in actual code, you'd need to keep track of the `std::unique_ptr` until you're ready to unregister the callback.)

In answer to a comment: to break down what the templates are doing behind the scenes, suppose for illustration that the internal name of the lambda class is `__lambda1`.  Then the `test()` function above generates code essentially equivalent to:

```
void c_callback_adaptor_lambda1(int x, int y, void* userData) {
    auto callable = reinterpret_cast<__lambda1*>(userData);
    (*callable)(x, y);
}

class __lambda1 {
public:
    __lambda1(int n) { ... }
    void operator()(int x, int y) const { std::cout << ...; }
    ...
private: ...
};

void test(int n) {
    auto cCallback = std::make_pair(
        std::make_unique<__lambda1>(n),
        c_callback_adaptor_lambda1);
    registerCallback(cCallback.second, cCallback.first.get());
    (void) cCallback.first.release();
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is lots of magic that is over my head. I hope I can decipher what exactly is happening here when staring at it long enough ;)

Comment: OK, I've added to the answer an example of what sort of code the templates are generating in the case of the example `test()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The PlayFab Cocos2dxSDK you have linked has since been upgraded to support lambda functions without modification to the SDK.

For Example:

```
PlayFabClientAPI::LoginWithEmailAddress(request,
    [](const LoginResult& result, void* customData) { /* your login-success lambda here */ },
    [](const PlayFabError& error, void* customData) { /* your error lambda here */ },
    nullptr);
```

Comment: Yes, because I coded them in and sent them the code to include it ;)